# How to preempt process after sched_min_granularity_ns expires in multi process scenario

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, linux-kernel

As per linux scheduler, sched_min_granularity_ns is the time every process executes before it is preempted and sched_latency_ns is total time in which every process finish execution for once.

Time slice is calculated as per no of running process/tasks and every process will run for alloted time slice. The current process will continue to run until time slice expires or other higher priority process preempts the current process.

As per my understanding, HIGHER PRIORITY process can only preempt other running process only after current running process runs for atleast sched_min_granularity_ns time.

Am I right ?

Once the time slice of current running process is expired and there are no active process ( may be waiting or sleeping), then current running process will continue running for next time slice.

Once the time slice of current running process is expired and if HIGHER/SAME PRIORITY process is active then current process will be preempted and there will CONTEXT SWITCH happen and next HIGHER/SAME PRIORITY process will run .

Here is my sysctl -a parameters

```
kernel.sched_latency_ns = 10000
kernel.sched_min_granularity_ns = 50
kernel.sched_wakeup_granularity_ns = 50
```

**I want to achieve following,**

```
Program1  Thread 1
Progrm2
Program1  Thread 2
Progrm2
Program1  Thread 3
Progrm2
Program1  Thread 4
Progrm2
Program1  Thread 5
```

**what I am getting**

```
Program1  Thread 1
Progrm2
Progrm2
Progrm2 
Progrm2
Program1  Thread 2
Progrm2
Progrm2
Progrm2
Progrm2 
Progrm2
Progrm2
Progrm2
Progrm2 
Progrm2
Program1  Thread 3
Progrm2
Progrm2
Progrm2 
Progrm2
Progrm2
Progrm2
Progrm2 
Progrm2

Program1  Thread 4
Progrm2
Progrm2 
Progrm2
Progrm2
Progrm2
Progrm2 
Progrm2

Program1  Thread 5
```

From the output is is clearly visible that the threads in program1 , is **not awakening** at proper time and that's why program2 continue running . **What can I do to make sure threads in program1 will awaken after sleep time elapsed ( 100 ns not 30-40microsec).**

**Here is my snippet of code : Program1**

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include "boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp"

#define NTHREADS 300 
#define NO_OF_LOOP 10


using namespace std;


std::string now_str()
{

    // Get current time from the clock, using microseconds resolution
    const boost::posix_time::ptime now =boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();

        // Get the time offset in current day
        const boost::posix_time::time_duration td = now.time_of_day();
        const long hours        = td.hours();
        const long minutes      = td.minutes();
        const long seconds      = td.seconds();
        const long microseconds = td.total_microseconds() - ((hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds) * 1000000);
        char buf[40];
        sprintf(buf, "Time Now : %02ld:%02ld:%02ld.%03ld", hours, minutes, seconds, microseconds);
        return buf;

}

void func_mul(int x, int n){
x*=n;   
    }

std::ostringstream out;
pthread_cond_t      cond[NTHREADS];
pthread_mutex_t     mutex1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

int state=0;

/* This is our thread function.  It is like main(), but for a thread*/
void *threadA(void *arg)
{ 

    long my_id = (long)arg;


    struct timespec s;
        s.tv_sec = 0;
        s.tv_nsec = 10;
    int i=0, j=0;   
    while(i < NO_OF_LOOP)
    {
           // Awaken or unblocked by thread (i-1) 
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
        if (state != my_id )
        {   
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond[my_id], &mutex1);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);

        // do the computation
        func_mul(my_id,my_id+1);

        out<<"Program1--"<< my_id<<"==>"<<now_str() << '\n';   

        //nanosleep(&s, NULL); 
        clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, 0, &s, NULL);


         // busy wait
         int count2 = 191000;
         while(count2--);
         int count3 = 191000;
         while(count3--);
         int count4 = 191000;
         while(count4--);


        // Set state to i+1 and wake up thread i+1 
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
        state = (my_id + 1) % NTHREADS;  
        pthread_cond_signal(&cond[state]); // Send signal to Thread (i+1) to awake  
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);

        ++i;

    }

}


int main(void)
{
    pthread_t             threadid[NTHREADS];
    ofstream fp;
    fp.open("result_program1.txt");
    // Initialization   
    for(int i=0;i<NTHREADS;i++)
        cond[i]= PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

    for(long i=0; i<NTHREADS; ++i) 
        pthread_create(&threadid[i], NULL, threadA, (void *)i);  

    for (long i=0; i<NTHREADS; ++i) 
        pthread_join(threadid[i], NULL);

    fp<<out.str();
    fp.close();
    return 0;
}
```

**Program 2**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<assert.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include "gmp.h"
#include<iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include "boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp"
#define NO_OF_LOOP 1000
using namespace std;


std::string now_str()
{

    // Get current time from the clock, using microseconds resolution
    const boost::posix_time::ptime now =boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();

        // Get the time offset in current day
        const boost::posix_time::time_duration td = now.time_of_day();
        const long hours        = td.hours();
        const long minutes      = td.minutes();
        const long seconds      = td.seconds();
        const long microseconds = td.total_microseconds() - ((hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds) * 1000000);
        char buf[40];
        sprintf(buf, "Time Now : %02ld:%02ld:%02ld.%03ld", hours, minutes, seconds, microseconds);
        return buf;

}

void func_mul(int x, int n){
x*=n;   
    }
int main(void)
{
    ofstream fp;
    std::ostringstream out;
    fp.open("result_program2.txt");
    for(int i=0;i<NO_OF_LOOP;i++)
    {
    func_mul(i,i+1);
    out<<"Program2 ==>"<<now_str() << '\n';  
    }   

    fp<<out.str();
    fp.close();
    return 0;
}
```

I am merging the output of two program to check the scheduling of two process.

Where I am making mistake ? How to ensure the Threads in Program1 must awake after exactly sched_min_granularity_ns time and preempt program2.

Thanks in advance. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and g++. Both program runs on same cpu core. Program1 nice value -20 and program2 nice value 0 (by default).

Comment: Please cite specific document(s) you read this from. There are several different documents for `sched_min_granularity_ns`, and they appear to have conflicting descriptions. Secondly, note that it will be scaled depending on the number of CPUs you have.  See https://www.suse.com/documentation/opensuse121/book_tuning/data/sec_tuning_taskscheduler_cfs.html

Comment: also you've used the linux-kernel tag but you have not explicitly said the kernel version you are using.  I know ubuntu kernels are a bit weird, but at least the base version is an important hint for readers.